# Is it possible and how to perform a join like operation which relies on the results of another observer

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2

Sorry but I am very new to RxJS but I am getting the hang of it slowly but one question I just cant seem to get an answer for this could be the way I am wording the question but here goes...

Lets say I have a table called users, this table is keyed via the users unique pushed key (so it unique!). I create a ref to it i.e '/users/' + id, and as expected I get my record for the user which contains a field called 'nurseryId', great just what I wanted!

The problem is and this is where it may be my understanding of RxJS, but I want to use the 'nurseryId' from within the 'users' record but to do this I need to create another ref to the '/nurseries/' + nurseryId table, how can I do this from within the users observable? Is it even possible?

I dont want to combine the two pieces of information and I want to create a route resolver but I need the results from the first fetch before I can start the second fetch???

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the 'user' ObjectObservable.

```
userObject.subscribe(userSnapshot=>{ 
//query here with userSnapshot.nurseryId as parameter
}
```

Comment: Cheers thanks, as I said I am new to Rx but I realised (which may sound stupid now!) that I can perform further subscribe operations from within a subscribe block. The problem I had was that I needed an ID from the first subscribe to get the information using a second subscribe. I have fixed this with (more reading to be honest!) flatMap.